# remove style from all child elements (including nested)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this code

```
    $(textObject).children().each(function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('style');
        console.log('removing style from first level element: '+this);

    });
```

But I want it to affect all nested elements as well, this one only affects first level children. I have also tried

```
$(this).children().removeAttr('style');
```

Which doesn't work.

I have also tried

```
$(this).children().css('font-size','');
```

which doesn't work either.

It's probably clear what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try

```
$(this).find('*').removeAttr('style');
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5nsQW/6/)

Comment: That's what I needed, simple and sweet thanks. And thanks to all you other guys for other good answers.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(this).find('[style]').addBack().removeAttr('style');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZMajS/)

Comment: what the addBack is for?

Comment: to add `this` element back to the collection

Answer (score 1):

You can access all children using:

```
$(textObject).find('*').each(function() {
        $(this).removeAttr('style');
        console.log('removing style from first level element: '+this);
});
```

And if you don't need to log it, just do:

```
$(textObject).find('*').removeAttr('style');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pure CSS using the asterisk.

You haven't specified what element `textObject` is referring to, but for the sake of argument, let's say it's a div with the id `element`

```
#element * { font-size: inherit; }
```

Or to force this style to override anything else already set on the child elements, use `!important`

```
#element * { font-size: inherit !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use * in find() method of jQuery. [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) will loop into one level while [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) will loop into nested levels. So your code would be

```
$(this).find('*').removeAttr('style');
```

and working code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/emYN8/)

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).children().removeAttr('style');`

Won't work because `.children()` will only access the direct children of `$(this)`.

There are multiple ways of doing this. You can use the second parameter of a jQuery selector to make it act as a filter.

```
// Select everything starting at whatever 'this' is refering to
$('*', this).removeAttr('style');
```

A demo can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/P7vaD/1/).

Or you can use the way Rex described.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be a whole lot easier for you to style the child elements with class names and remove the styles by toggling the class name with jQuery?

This markup:

```
<div class="parent fancy-styles">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
.fancy-styles .child {
  /* styling */
}
```

And then trigger:

```
$(".parent").toggleClass("fancy-styles")
```